# memory leak on IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE with abstract CWinThread derived class

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc, abstract-class

Visual Studio (I'm using 2010 but I've tried on other versions) is telling me I've got a memory leak on the line of my class that executes the IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE macro.

Steps to Reproduce.

Create a basic MFC Dialog Application.
Add a class derived from CWinThread using the Class Wizard:

Header:

```
class CMyThread : public CWinThread
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyThread)

protected:
    CMyThread();           // protected constructor used by dynamic creation

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

CPP:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestProject.h"
#include "MyThread.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

// CMyThread

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMyThread, CWinThread)

CMyThread::CMyThread()
{
}

BOOL CMyThread::InitInstance()
{
    // TODO:  perform and per-thread initialization here
    return TRUE;
}

int CMyThread::ExitInstance()
{
    // TODO:  perform any per-thread cleanup here
    return CWinThread::ExitInstance();
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyThread, CWinThread)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMyThread message handlers
```

Now, add an abstract CWinThread Derived class to the header:

```
class CThreadAbstract : public CWinThread
{
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance() = 0;
    virtual int ExitInstance() = 0;
};
```

And change your original CWinThread derived class to be derived from CThreadAbstract instead:

```
class CMyThread : public CThreadAbstract 
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyThread)

protected:
    CMyThread();           // protected constructor used by dynamic creation

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();
    virtual int ExitInstance();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

Now, instantiate an instance of your thread from the dialog class (OnInitDialog) and shut it down:

```
CMyThread * pMyThread = (CMyThread *)AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyThread),0,0,CREATE_SUSPENDED);
if (pMyThread)
{
    pMyThread->m_bAutoDelete = false;
    pMyThread->ResumeThread();
}

if (pMyThread)
{
    pMyThread->PostThreadMessage(WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
    pMyThread = NULL;
}
```

Run the app in the debugger and click the OK button (or hit esc) to shut it down.

Whalla!  Memory leak that points to:

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CMyThread, CWinThread)
```

Obviously I'm not real sure exactly what's happening here with the IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE to cause this.  I've read through the MSDN docs and saw where it says that the macro will instantiate an instance of the class so I'm guessing that this is what isn't being cleaned up properly but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: When you set m_bAutoDelete false you become responsible for deleting the CMyThread object.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP so you are saying that the leak isn't from a 2nd instance being created but from the original instance?  whoever down voted the question, do you mind telling me what is bad form about the question?

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP Nevermind my previous question.  I removed setting the autodelete flag and the leak went away as you suggested.  I then went to read the MSDN docs and sure enough it says exactly the same thing.  Its strange that I've always used CWinThread objects this way and always shutdown the thread the same way but never ran into this before (which is why I thought it was related to the use of the abstract class).  I always thought the autodelete flag was related to thread termination not object cleanup (oops).  If you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set m_bAutoDelete false you become responsible for deleting the CMyThread object.